# valgrind : what does the following summary tells

Tags: valgrind, segmentation-fault

First have a look at my code .It is giving runtime error(sigsegv) on an online judge, though works perfetly fine on my computer.Please help me find out the error.

The constraints are:

0< t1 <1000000

0< num <100000000

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<malloc.h>

int *a;

int main()

{

   a = malloc(sizeof(int)*100000000);



   int  t=3,j,k1,k=1,n=0,i,t1,num;



   for(i=1;i<10000;i++)

      {

                  // m=i*i;

                   n=n+t;

                   for(j=i*i;j<=n;j++)



                                    a[j]=k;



                   k++;

                   t=t+2;



     }

  scanf("%d",&t1);



   for(k1=0;k1<t1;k1++)

   {

        scanf("%d",&num);

        printf("%d\n",a[num]);

   }

  free(a);

  //getch();

   return 0;

}
```

I ran this simple code  using valgrind. It gave the following output,i am newbie to valgrind so please tell me what does it mean.

```
singu@singu-Studio-1450 ~ $ valgrind --leak-check=yes ./doors
==4732== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4732== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4732== Using Valgrind-3.6.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4732== Command: ./doors
==4732== 
==4732== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x51c3040, 0x1cf3b440)     (undefined)
==4732== Invalid write of size 4
==4732==    at 0x400662: main (doors.c:16)
==4732==  Address 0x1cf3b440 is 0 bytes after a block of size 400,000,000 alloc'd
==4732==    at 0x4C28FAC: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==4732==    by 0x400605: main (doors.c:6)
==4732== 
^C==4732== 
==4732== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4732==     in use at exit: 400,000,000 bytes in 1 blocks
==4732==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 400,000,000 bytes allocated
==4732== 
==4732== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4732==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4732==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4732==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4732==    still reachable: 400,000,000 bytes in 1 blocks
==4732==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4732== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==4732== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==4732== 
==4732== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4732== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind basically tells you two things here:

1° You're writing to a memory location that you didn't allocate. This is the meaning of the `invalid write` message. This write is of size 4 (an integer) and occurs on line 16 of doors.c.
This is probably the cause for your segmentation fault. My guess is that your a[j] occurs out of the range of the array for some values of j, so you want to properly check that (more specifically, remember that arrays are 0-indexed, and so the range of an array a of size s is a[0] to a[s-1]).
You should print j and check if it is less than 10,000 to see if there is a problem.

2° When exiting, you have done 1 alloc, but 0 free, so you don't free the 400,000 bytes you allocated. However, you still have a pointer on it at exit, so it is `still reachable`.

Comment: @dureull I can't find any out of range array allocation.

Comment: To be even more precise, Valgrind actually tells you that you're writing at the end of your array at address 0x1cf3b440, which is a[100000000], so there is a write out of range.

Comment: @dureull i printed the a[100000000] value it is zero where as it should have been some +value. I can't understand the fault please help me in correcting the code

Comment: Did you print the value of j? Printing a non allocated value such as a[100000000] cannot give you any meaningful information. However, your n is the sum of t, an arithmetic sequence, and equals to 1,0001/2*(3 + 2,0003), ie 100,040,003 which is greater than 100,000,000. Thus your problem. I can't debug your program because I don't know what purpose it serves. The initial question was to understand the ouput of valgrind, which I explained.

Comment: i printed the value of j it is not  greater than 99999999 .why you said to check if j < 10000,shouldn't i check if its <10000^2

Comment: My bad, my computation was just plain wrong. Also, executing your program under valgrind gives me no error... What input did you provide to the scanf?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15790/discussion-between-sandyroddick-and-dureuill)